# Opening Water Bottle On Shabbath

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, makeh-befatish

Can one open a water bottle with a plastic cap on Shabbath? Or would they be violating mechateich?

Comment: Has the water bottle been opened before?

Comment: Is the bottle cap plastic or metal? Due to the way caps are formed, plastic is easier to allow than metal

Answer (score 0):

This is a very disputed topic. Parts of the machlokes are the understanding of all melachos involved (not only mechatech but also makkeh bepatish). One must also know how the bottle caps are created or if they look the same as they did when various achronim discussed the topic.

The  שמירת שבת כהלכתה פרק ט recommends opening all bottles and packages before shabbos to avoid any issues. He also bring rabbi shlomo Zaman Auerbach opinion that was more lenient (but nor a blanket heter).

See this article that goes into further depth https://din.org.il/2017/01/05/%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%97%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA-7/